# HTML 5 download attribute showing validation error in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: html, attributes, download

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.downloadDxForm, text: FileName" download="test">
```

For the above mark up, the visual stufio editor shows the error : Attribute download is not a valid attribute of element 'a'.

Also when I check in chrome, the attribute does not function as well.

Comment: do you have your targeted schema set to HTML5?

Comment: Yes, I checked, it is set to HTML5.